# how to implement key up event in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have three textboxes, one has 'quantity', the second has 'unit price' and the third has 'total'. what i want is to display the product of 'quantity' and 'unit price' into the 'total' textbox using the keyup trigger.

I am just beginning asp.net
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The focus of your application wont lie on the form itself so I would suggest putting the event in each textbox.

There is for sure a smoother solution but this worked for me:

```
Private Sub TextBoxQuantity_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBoxQuantity.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        TextBoxTotal.Text = TextBoxQuantity.Text & vbTab & TextBoxUnitPrice.Text
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxUnitPrice_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBoxUnitPrice.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        TextBoxTotal.Text = TextBoxQuantity.Text & vbTab & TextBoxUnitPrice.Text
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxTotal_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBoxTotal.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        TextBoxTotal.Text = TextBoxQuantity.Text & vbTab & TextBoxUnitPrice.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

[This](http://vb.net-informations.com/gui/key-press-vb.htm) is a wiki page on VB.net KeyPress-Event. Please read it to avoid further questions on this topic.